# CarouselPage scrolling prevents ImageButton Released event firing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page which is a child of a CarouselPage. The page has ImageButtons on it which have pressed and released events.

Something happens when the pressed event fires and it stops when the released event fires.

The problem I have is when you push a button down and then slide left or right causing the carousel animation to take effect the released event from the currently held button no longer fires.

This is not an issue if the user switches to another page as I can use the page changed event to tidy up.

The problem is if you start sliding to the next page and then stop it pings back to the current one and no event fires at all.

I have looked for events that may fire in this scenario but have not found anything yet.

I need a way to either get the released events to still fire or a means of detecting a partial carousel scroll so that I can do the same from another event.

I am using the latest version of everything, testing in the emulator and developing solely for Android.

ImageButton definition

```
<ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Source="up.png" Pressed="ImageButton_OnPressed" Released="ImageButton_OnReleased" BackgroundColor="Transparent" CommandParameter="U"></ImageButton>
```

Code behind

```
        private void ImageButton_OnPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Action start action
        }

        private void ImageButton_OnReleased(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Action stop action
        }
```

Page Change event on CarouselPage

```
private void MainPage_OnCurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Action stop all actions on page
        }
```

Comment: How are you tracking the pressed and released events?

Comment: @iSpain17 I have added examples of an Image button and what the different event handlers do. I have temporarily got around this by replacing the page in question with a landing page that has a button to push the page as a new one. This way its no longer part of the carousel.